# How can I pull every branch from "origin" remote and push to our "backup" remote

Tags: git, backup

I have created a new user who will be in charge of backing up/syncing the 'origin' remote with another remote we've called 'backup'. Our Origin remote is on our lcoa network and the backup remove is hosted on bitbucket.

I want the user to pull in all branches that exist on Origin (all feature branches, etc) and once it has pulled those, it should push everything to the 'backup' remote.

What commands do I need to achieve this? Or is there another way?

Comment: When you say "pull every branch", is it safe to assume that you really mean "fetch every branch"? The distinction in important in Git. A pull is just a fetch, followed by a merge.

Comment: Well wouldn't the backup user need to have all the changes detected with a fetch merged into his local repository? (aka a pull?) Otherwise, how will the backup user push the changes to a different repository?

Comment: It's all references. Git is just a tree of commits, with movable Post-it notes (references) attached.

Comment: Assuming you need 'pull all' and 'push all', you could use [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) and `git push REMOTE --all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you don't really want to merge the remote `origin` branches to the local branches in the local repo, then to "backup" the `origin` branches in their current state to the Bitbucket repo, you can simply use this:

```
git fetch origin && git push backup refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

This does the following:

1. Fetches the current state of the branches on `origin` and stores that state in the remote-tracking branches (references) under `.git/refs/remotes/origin/`.
2. If the fetch succeeds, then the push command is executed (that is what the `&&` is for). The push uses a refspec to say "take all the remote-tracking branches under `.git/refs/remotes/origin/`, and push them to the remote `backup` into branches with the same name.

   The destination side of the refspec,

   ```
   refs/heads/*
   ```

   is not symmetrical with the source side,

   ```
   refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```

   because each side of the colon `:` is relative to the source and destination repo:

   - On the source side (the local repo), the `origin` remote-tracking branches are all stored under `.git/refs/remotes/origin/`.
   - On the desitation side (the backup repo), local branches are stored under `.git/refs/heads/`. This is why the right-hand side of the refspec has to match that.

### Modified Alternative Solution

A slightly different way you could do this is to create a bare repository as a "relay", and configure it in such a way that all you need to do is use

```
git fetch origin && git push backup --all
```

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a bare repo

   ```
   git init --bare
   ```
2. Add the source and destination remotes

   ```
   git remote add origin <url-or-path-to-your-origin-remote>
   git remote add backup <bitbucket-repo-url>
   ```
3. Modify the relay repo's to fetch configuration for the `origin` remote.

   ```
   git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
   ```

Now the relay repo is properly configured to fetch the local branches from the remote `origin`, and store them as local branches in itself with a simple

```
git fetch origin
```

In addition, since they're now local branches stored under `.git/refs/heads/`, you can push them all at once to the `backup` remote with a simple

```
git push backup --all
```

Comment: Im giving this a go now. Its writing objects at the moment so I'll respond when it completes. Our server is just a computer running windows, is there a way to automate this process? I noticed that when I enter the command I need to then enter the password for the user twice (once for the fetch and once for the push i guess?)

Comment: Are you using Bitbucket to host both remote repositories? They should have instructions on how to setup your Bash profile so that you don't have to enter a password for either HTTPS or SSH remote URLs.

Comment: Our repository is on the local network for quicker access, but the backup repository is on bit bucket. Oh PS: The operation completed successfully and it worked really well. I am going to accept your answer but it would bee awesome if you could give me a hand on automating all this.

Comment: Edit: Oh and I am doing all my work in the Terminal that pops up when you press the Terminal button in SourceTree.

Comment: If you want to automate this, you should take a look into installing Git on your Windows server, then using Batch or Powershell scripts to automate the command that I gave in my answer. You could probably set it up as a regularly recurring job or something. If you get stuck, then please consider asking another question, but be mindful of whether the question would be a better fit on [sf]. Be sure to pay attention to [what's on-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what's on-topic for Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Remember that [sf] is for professional production servers. They may or may not allow questions about development server environments. If it doubt, search or ask on their [meta site](http://meta.serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In that case why don't you backup the git repoistory with out using the push and pull.

git clone other/repo.git --- this will backup every repository of its remote.

Or

Setup the repo: git clone --mirror user@origin:/repo.git

After that refresh the backup: git remote update from the clone location.

You can use the bash commands to create a sh file and will automate this for you.

Comment: FYI, `git remote update` is an older way to update from a remote, the newer preferred method is to simply use `git fetch`.